# Getting runtime error in basic code in code jam

Tags: java, runtime-error

/*package whatever //do not write package name here */

```
import java.util.*;

class Nested {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
        int t=in.nextInt();
        while(t-->0)
        {
            String input=in.nextLine();
            //solve(input);
        }
    }
    
}
```

I am passing

> 1
>
> 1

as input but it is showing me runtime error...don't know why because its working fine on geeksforgeeks ide

Comment: Add the complete error message

Comment: it is just showing RE

Comment: This looks fine... add a screenshot of your error or something. We can't help you without more info

Comment: I think you want `.next()` not `.nextLine()`

Comment: For those asking for extra info. This is Google Code Jam, it doesn't give error messages other than "RE - Runtime Error", "WA - wrong answer", "TLE - Time Limit Exceeded"

Comment: Even Google Code Jam provides a problem statement.  You did not.  I don't know how others know what your code is supposed to do.

Comment: Put this line: `in.nextLine();` directly **after** your: `int t=in.nextInt();` code line so that it consumes the newline character when the ENTER key was hit entering the integer value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code Jam accept classname as Solution
That was the issue!

Thanks a lot everyone for helping!